# Replacing right join with derived table to left join

Tags: mysql, left-join, derived-table

How do i write this query, with left join. since the framework i use doesn't support right join i need to rewrite the query. Can any one suggest me a possible solution.

```
select Audit.history_id,Audit.field,modifiedtime,operation from Audit right join (select History.history_id from History where refid=2000000020088 order by
modifiedtime limit 5) as Hist on Audit.history_id=Hist.history_id;

    desc Audit
    +------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | AUDIT_ID         | bigint(19) |      | PRI | 0       |       |
    | HISTORY_ID       | bigint(19) |      | MUL | 0       |       |
    | FIELD            | varchar(50)       |     |         |       |
    | OLD_VALUE        | varchar(50)| YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | NEW_VALUE        | varchar(50)| YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

desc History
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| HISTORY_ID    | bigint(19)  |      | PRI | 0                   |       |
| REFID         | bigint(19)  |      | MUL | 0                   |       |
| OPERATION     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| MODIFIED_TIME | datetime    |      |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: The query looks a bit strange: You will always get the first five records from History where refid=2000000020088 without taking history_id into account.
Shouldn't it be:
select History.history_id from History where refid=2000000020088 and History.history_id = Audit.history_id order by
modifiedtime limit 5???

Comment: There will be more number of history entries, Initially i show the first 5, then the next 5 and goes on.

Comment: OK, but every audit record will always be joined with the same first five records returned by the subquery.

Comment: Each history may have zero or one or more audit entries.

Comment: Ah OK, the right join confused me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply switch the relations for a left join:

> In practice, explicit right outer joins are rarely used, since they can always be replaced with left outer joins (with the table order switched) and provide no additional functionality.

Source:[Wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Right_outer_join)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    Audit.history_id,Audit.field,modifiedtime,operation 
from    
    (
        select History.history_id 
        from History where refid=2000000020088 
        order by modifiedtime limit 5            
    ) as Hist 
    left join Audit on (Audit.history_id = Hist.history_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will produce exactly same output as the one you have now, but it might give you the right idea:

select Audit.history_id, Audit.field, History.modifiedtime, History.operation 
from History
left join Audit on Audit.history_id=History.history_id
where History.refid=2000000020088
order by History.modifiedtime